# How i can allow passing passwords that contain unsafe words

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ldap

I am working on an asp.net MVC4 web application, and for the login i am using form authentication that is connected to our AD using LDAP connection string, as follow. 
The login Get action method:-

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    returnUrl = TempData["returnUrl"] != null ? TempData["returnUrl"].ToString() : String.Empty;
    List<String> domains = new List<String>();
    domains.Add("*****");
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    ViewBag.Domains = domains;
    return View();
}
```

The Login Post action method:-

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    MembershipProvider domainProvider;
    domainProvider = Membership.Providers["TestDomain1ADMembershipProvider"];
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Validate the user with the membership system.
        if (domainProvider.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {  
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            List<String> domains2 = new List<String>();
            domains2.Add("****");
            ViewBag.Domains = domains2;
            return View(model);
        }

        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
    List<String> domains = new List<String>();
    domains.Add("****");
    ViewBag.Domains = domains;
    return View(model);
}
```

Now i have been using this system for 5 years and never face any issue with user login. but today a new user mentioned that when he tried to login to the system he will get an error "*Error while processing your request.*", and this error will be raised in our system if an unhandled exception is being raised. and i checked the IIS log and i can see that the user did not access the system.

so the only issue i can think of is that the user's password contain characters which MVC does not allow. for example i tried to type this password `<script>@1234` along with my username, and instead of getting this message "*The user name or password provided is incorrect.*" , i got the same exception  "*Error while processing your request.*".. of course i can not ask the user to mention his password, but i am not sure how i can allow MVC to accept any password passed to it? as i can not think of any other problem...because usually when users login to the application they either; login successfully Or get "The user name or password provided is incorrect." , but i never face a problem where the user get an exception... which i were able to replicate by passing unsafe characters `<script>@1234`

Comment: Set a breakpoint within the `Login(LoginModel, string)` method and verify that the model is being serialized correctly. It might be an issue in MVC rather than AD/LDAP. If it *is* an issue with AD, it's likely throwing an exception at `ValidateUser` that's being hidden behind the generic HTTP 500 error. You can probably get more info by adding a try/catch block and inspecting/logging the exception.

Comment: @p.s.w.g when i debug the application inside visual studio and i type the following password `<script>` the break point on the Post login action method `Login(LoginModel, string)` will NOT be reached. and instead i will get the following exception `A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Password="<script>").` of course if this error is raised on live server, the users will get `Error while processing ....`

Comment: .. so can i allow the `Login(LoginModel, string)` post action method to accept unsafe characters ?

Answer (score 3):

In your `LoginModel` make add the [`AllowHtmlAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute) to the `Password` field. This will bypass the check against input like `<script>`.

```
[AllowHtml]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Use it sparing, of course. MVC is trying to protect you from script injection attacks, so you should only disable this check in a few cases where you can be sure the value is handled safely. (In this case, passwords should never be displayed to the user, so even if there is HTML in it, it cannot inject HTML onto the page).

Alternatively, if you cannot alter the `LoginModel` class, you could try adding the [`ValidateInputAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.validateinputattribute) to your `Login` POST method.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply... now i can access all the classes but which appraoch you prefer? using `[AllowHtml]` or `[ValidateInput(false)]`? second question, now generally speaking , can a password inside AD contain characters that can not be passed to MVC? if the answer is yes, then for-sure i need to modify my application as mentioned in your reply, even if it is not related to my current problem.. is this correct? as my application will have a problem if the user's password contain characters which MVC consider as unsafe?

Comment: @testtest I'd preffer `[AllowHtml]` because it removes the input validation for only that one property. For your second question, I do not know of any such characters, but you might want to experiment with various control characters (backspace, null character, etc.) to be sure. On the other hand, if someone actually is using control characters, they probably are doing something suspicious anyway.

Comment: ok fine, but at the end i am not allowing users to create passwords that contain unsafe words, i am just want to allow them to login to my application.. and since i am not going to store the password or show it to any user, so i think using [AllowHtml] on the password variable only, would still be considered safe.. otherwise the user will not be able to login to the system...

Comment: Correct. This question made me realize that I should probably make it standard practice in my MVC applications as well. Passwords often have characters and patterns that might be considered unsafe elsewhere and they should be handled more permissively than other text input.

Comment: yes and from my side also.. but the strange thing is that i did not find any article or similar problem on stackoverflow , i mean seems no one faced this issue before :)